# conditional select with time adding calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
id | PlateNumber |  ImgDate |    ImgTime|
1  | abc123 |      2020-03-01 |  09:10:33|
2  | qwe128 |      2020-03-02|   09:13:39|
3  | abc123 |      2020-03-01|   09:11:21|
```

So, there are too many repeated plate numbers based on image capturing time.
I need a select statement that returns repeated records only when there is a time difference of more than 3 minutes. I hope that this makes sense.
Please help
Thank you guys!

Comment: which sql engine are you using? please tag it.

Comment: Why are you storing date & time in two columns? It would be better to just use a single `timestamp` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a bit more info, but you would want to compare the current row with the previous one (for each PlateNumber). You can do that using an analytical function like LAG.

```
WITH CTE as (
Select 
  id
  ,PlateNumber
  ,ImgDate
  ,ImgTime
  ,LAG(ImgDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PlateNumber ORDER BY ImgDate,ImgTime) as PreviousDate
  ,LAG(ImgTime) OVER (PARTITION BY PlateNumber ORDER BY ImgDate,ImgTime) as PreviousImgTime
FROM YourTable
)
Select id
  ,PlateNumber
  ,ImgDate
  ,ImgTime
FROM CTE
  WHERE (PreviousDate is null and PreviousImgTime is null) -- to keep the first occurence
  OR ( 
      DATEDIFF(second,
         DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, PreviousDate)) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, PreviousImgTime), PreviousImgTime) ,
         DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, ImgDate)) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, ImgTime), ImgTime) 
         ) > 180
      )
```

If your columns are DATE and TIME datatype

```
 OR ( 
          DATEDIFF(second,
            cast(PreviousDate as DATETIME) +cast(PreviousImgTime as DATETIME) ,
            cast(ImgDate as DATETIME) + cast(ImgTime as DATETIME), 
            ) > 180
          )
```

Comment: what datatypes are your ImgDate  and ImgTime ? if they are both datetime, can I assume that the date part is alwasy 0 for ImgTime and that the time part is always 0 for ImgDate  ?

Comment: Both are from the same column (Data Type = DateTime), I just separated them in a view.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can add `datetime` values, so you can do this basically just with `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, v.dt,
             lag(dt) over (partition by platenumber order by dt) as prev_dt
      from t cross apply
           (values (convert(datetime, t.imgdate) + convert(datetime, t.imgtime))
           ) as v(dt)
     ) t
where prev_dt is null or prev_dt < dateadd(minute, -3, dt);
```